# Is SPF record valid?

Tags: domain-name-system, sendmail, spf

I am getting "softfail error" for the current spf record what should i do?

This is the original mail i got from my domain.

I added the spf record in my dns.

```
v=spf1 mx mx:smtp.secureserver.net include:smtp.secureserver.net ~all
```

Unfortunately I entered smtp server name in spf record.

Here I am using my domain only for sending purpose.So, I didn't add any MX records.
In the SPF record my domain has to be passed for the span checking. What are the things i need to focus?

Could you please explain? How should i write the SPF record

```
Delivered-To: nava@gridlex.com
Received: by 10.229.150.13 with SMTP id w13csp108400qcv;
    Fri, 18 May 2012 06:05:02 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.224.34.4 with SMTP id j4mr22611239qad.61.1337346302689;
    Fri, 18 May 2012 06:05:02 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <dr@pharma.com>
Received: from ip-10-111-7-139.ec2.internal (ec2-50-16-79-25.compute-1.amazonaws.com.  [50.16.79.25])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id a9si3748068qcu.106.2012.05.18.06.05.02
    (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=OTHER);
    Fri, 18 May 2012 06:05:02 -0700 (PDT)
    Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning dr@pharma.com does not designate 50.16.79.25 as permitted sender) client-ip=50.16.79.25;
   Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning dr@pharma.com does not designate 50.16.79.25 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=dr@pharma.com
   Received: from ip-10-111-7-139.ec2.internal (localhost [127.0.0.1])
by ip-10-111-7-139.ec2.internal (8.14.4/8.14.4/Debian-2ubuntu1) with ESMTP id q4ID4YvM004650
for <nava@gridlex.com>; Fri, 18 May 2012 13:04:34 GMT
   Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
   MIME-Version: 1.0
   Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
   Subject: Hi Nava
   From: dr@pharma.com
   To: nava@gridlex.com
   Date: Fri, 18 May 2012 13:04:34 -0000
   Message-ID: <20120518130434.4647.68243@ip-10-111-7-139.ec2.internal>

   Sample Ignore
```

Will this work?

```
  v=spf1 ?include:pharma.com -all
```

Comment: Do you run pharma.com?

Comment: pharmaflare.com

Comment: Well, `v=spf1 ?include:pharma.com -all` won't work for that.

Comment: @ceejayoz sorry, v=spf1 ?include:pharmaflare.com -all only It is recently changed

Comment: @all sorry for the mis communication.The site we own is "pharmaflare.com" while I am editing the post it was renamed to all unfortunately.I was tried to rename for the header part and i didn't notice.please leave the pharma.com

Comment: @ChrisS I am refirecting my domain mails to my gmail.I wanna setup one domain mail.from that i need to send mail to my personal mail.

Comment: @ChrisS Oh Sorry man I think I didn't get your questions.Could you please give me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include:pharma.com - means that receiving server should check SPF record for pharma.com first and then return to check.. nothing.

I suggest you add correct MX record and use default SPF:
`v=spf1 +a +mx ~all`

or if you surely don't need mx use this with ip of your server:
`v=spf1 +a +ip4:IP.AD.DR.ES ~all` or `v=spf1 +a +a:smtp.yourservername.tld ~all`

if you don't need to send e-mail from other servers - replace `~all` with `-all`.

Read [a good article](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch9/spf.html) on SPF record format.

Comment: What's with the superfluous plus signs? Also, some servers will hold it against you that your SPF record ends in "~all" (aka, I don't know what I'm doing).

Comment: fine. v=spf1 a mx ip4:<my ip> include:pharma.com -all  will this be fine?

Comment: + can be omitted, but I used to add it.

Comment: why do you need `include:pharma.com`?
this will just add checks from SPF record for pharma.com, which does not exists now.

Comment: @DukeLion yes dude typo mistake "pharmaflare.com" sorry

Comment: Again, you do not need to include SPF record to itself.

Comment: @DukeLion Sorry for the interruption. May i get little bit more explanation please?

Comment: When SPF checker meet include directive - it loads SPF record from mentioned domain and continues check with this SPF record. After that it returns to parent record. In your case it may check same record twice. It will work, but is useless

Comment: @DukeLion Ya Got your point..It check the ip and domain also since mentioned both. am i right? I will do the change means I ll remove the domain